# Type Error in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to make a wsgi server following this tutorial [Let's Build a Web Server.](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part2/)
But getting error `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes` using below code in python 3.5.2.

```
import io
env['wsgi.input']        = io.StringIO(self.request_data)
```

How can I fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, that tutorial uses python2, so you may run into additional problems if you try to apply it directly to python3

According to PEP3333 (the WSGI specification updated for python3) the `wsgi.input` [environ variable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#environ-variables) should be a byte stream, not a text stream, so you should use `io.BytesIO()`, not `io.StringIO`.

The error you currently get ist because your `self.request_data` is `bytes`, but `io.StringIO()` requires its argument to be a `str`.